# The method getWorkbook(File) is undefined for the type Workbook

Tags: java, excel, testng

iam getting the following error, in the program

"The method getWorkbook(File) is undefined for the type Workbook" at the Workbook wb1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new java.io.File(Path));

```
package ExcelTest;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import java.io.*;  

import jxl.Cell;  
import jxl.Sheet;  
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;  
import jxl.read.biff.File; 

public class Sample {

    private static final String Path = null;
    @DataProvider(name="test")
    public Object[][] createdata1()throws Exception
    {
        Object[][] retobj = getexcel();
        return retobj;

    }


    private String[][] getexcel() throws Exception
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[][] tabarray = null;
        try {
            Workbook wb1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new java.io.File(Path));
           // Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new java.io.File(path));

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("userlogin");

            Cell tablestart = sheet.findCell("login");

            int startrow = tablestart.getRow();
            int startcol = tablestart.getColumn();

            Cell tableend = sheet.findCell("login",startcol+1,startrow+1,100, 64000, false);

            int endrow = tableend.getRow();
            int endcol = tableend.getColumn();

            System.out.println("startRow="+startrow+", endRow="+endrow+"," + "startCol="+startcol+", endCol="+endcol);

             tabarray = new String[endrow - startrow + 1][endcol - startcol + 1];

            int ci = 0;
            for(int i = startrow +1 ;i<endrow;i++,ci++)
            {

                int cj = 0;
                for(int j = startcol + 1;j<endcol;j++,cj++)
                {
                    tabarray[ci][cj] = sheet.getCell(j,i).getContents();
                    System.out.println(tabarray[ci][cj]);

                }   
            }

        } catch (BiffException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tabarray;
    }

}
```

i have gone through link "[Reading content from an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326031/reading-content-from-an-excel-file)" but it does'nt solve my problem can anyone suggest me where iam going wrong. ?

Comment: The question you linked is using an old version of Apache poi. In the new version `Workbook.getWorkbook(file)` has been replaced by `WorkbookFactory.create(file)`.

Comment: Thank you very much i changed the API.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No ryvantage my problem isn't got solved iam trying still with latest poi.